# Is it possible to connect more than one device on the same SPI?

Tags: spi, i2c

Is it possible for someone to connect multiple sensors to the same microcontroller's SPI or I2C port?
If it's possible, how would someone alternate between devices?

Comment: Yes, that's what they're designed for.  Read up on SPI and you'll soon see how.  Just google "SPI" and hit the wikipedia page. It'll take you 5 seconds.

Comment: Is it the same for I2C?

Comment: I2C works differently, but yes, it has multiple devices.

Comment: You typically alternate between SPI devices by running a separate Slave Select line to each one, though some devices like the MCP23S17 also support a "soft" addressing scheme, where you mention a device ID in your request and only the device with that ID will respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SPI:**
The master can work with slaves in two modes: with independent slaves or cooperative slaves.

- With independent slaves I just need to select them with the uC's I/O
  pins.
- With cooperative slaves I need to "daisy-chain" them (I
  won't be using this).

**I2C:**
It has a 2 line bus (clock and data) and I just need to connect them to Vdd and the master and slave devices.

Comment: Important to note, that _daisy-chaining_ is possible only with devices that support it, i.e. simple things like shift registers.